# Why 3rd-party DLL need pre-load in unit test

Tags: c#, .net, unit-testing, dll, .net-assembly

We have a 3rd party DLL(`lib1.dll`), it's Win32 .NET assembly. Meanwhile, we wrote a class library(`lib2.dll`) which reference `lib1.dll`.

After that, we wrote unit test(via `NUnit`) to test the `lib2`, and the exception happens:

```
Could not load file or assembly or one of its dependencies.
```

lib1:

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;

public class Helper
{
    public Helper()
    {
    }

    public static void Execute()
    {
        Trace.WriteLine(DateTime.Now);
    }
}
```

lib2:

```
namespace lib2
{
    public class Manager
    {
        public int Add(int a, int b)
        {
            Helper.Execute();
            return a + b;
        }
    }
}
```

NUnit test:

```
[Test]
public void Foo()
{
    var manager = new Manager();
    Assert.AreEqual(5, manager.Add(2,3));
}
```

Our code is same behavior like above. When the test executes, the `Helper.Execute()` would throw an exception said it could not load assembly `lib1.DLL`.

The strangest thing is we cannot reproduce this issue. However, we can workaround this by add a line pre-load code like this:

```
[Test]
public void Foo()
{
    var pre_load = new Helper();
    var manager = new Manager();
    Assert.AreEqual(5, manager.Add(2,3));
}
```

But we still don't know the root cause. Does anyone met this issue before or can anyone give me some hints how to do diagnostics?

Comment: Does it say anything after that message?

Comment: @LegionMammal978 No. That's the only exception I can get, no `InnerException`, no other useful messages.

Comment: @JerryBian make sure that the 3rd party dll was copied into the test execution dir....

Comment: @OldFox Sure it was.